# Library for encoding .wav format to .g729 GroovyCodecs

Tags: c#, audio

I am trying to use library:

https://github.com/jongoochgithub/GroovyCodecs/tree/master/G729

There isnt explained or shown how it works exactly. I've never had contact with audio formatting before. And I dont know what I do wrong.

What i do:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[60000];
...
G729Decoder decoder = new G729Decoder();
byte[] samples = decoder.Process(buffer);

G729Encoder encoder = new G729Encoder();
byte[] samples1 = encoder.Process(samples);
```

I read file with extension .g729 and use G729Decoder.Process to change it on .wav. I can save this file and open audio.

But I dont understand why when I decoder and next coder this file the byte[] contains other bytes. And saving this file causes the audio path to be damaged.

Edit:
Library work just it is Lossy compression and array look deferent. I didnt two small mistakes where my code spoiled received bytes.

Advice:
When you read .wav skip 46 first bytes.
when you do loop with encoder and decoder array should be the same size.

Comment: Which on byte[] variables? sample1 or samples ?  Which other bytes it contain? Please, clarify your question and provide functional code listing with files pathes etc.

Comment: Generally, my problem is that I can't encode the .wav file to .g729. I am using two class from GroovyCodecs/G729/ G729Decoder and G729Encoder. I think the easiest way to try to explain this is to decode and re-encode the same file. Where would I expect to receive the same arrays. However, this does not happen. Samples and samples1 they look like two different arrays.

Comment: buffer* and samples1 look like two different arrays.

Comment: I think it is normal that you can get different arrays because the conversion from WAV to G729 is audio compression, so you can have loses of information. Even if your source file was in G729 format, I think, it is difficult to obtain 2 exact same arrays of bytes before and after audio compression. What happen when you are trying to play it ?

Comment: I hear only noise. I find information maybe I should revert bytes in my array before decoder. Maybe file which i have was inverted before save so i trying do it.